# Set default Document Mode to 10 from Edge

Tags: internet-explorer

need help to set the internet explorer default document mode to 10 for every user. Currently document mode is edge but would to update it [Registry Created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk5qq.png)

[Webpage Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WPje.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions available for this requirement.

**(1) By setting the Registry key.**

-> You can go to the path below in Registry Editor.

```html
1)For 32 bit machine:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

2)For 64 bit machine:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION 

Or 

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

-> Add new **DWORD 32 bit** key and name it as **iexplore.exe**.

-> Double click on it and set its value to **2710** (Hexadecimal value).

[image]

-> Restart the IE and check the document mode using developer tools.

I try to search for Group Policy Setting for this setting but did not get any information for the same.

**(2) You can also try to use** **Enterprise Mode Site List Manager**

Enterprise Mode is a compatibility mode that runs on Internet Explorer 11, letting websites render using a modified browser configuration that’s designed to emulate either Windows Internet Explorer 8 or Windows Internet Explorer 7, avoiding the common compatibility problems associated with web apps written and tested on older versions of Internet Explorer.

You can use IE11 and the Enterprise Mode Site List Manager to add individual website domains and domain paths and to specify whether the site renders using Enterprise Mode or the default mode.

[image]

Reference:

(1) [Enterprise Mode Site List Manager (schema v.2)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49974)

(2) [Use the Enterprise Mode Site List Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/use-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-manager)

Comment: I tried above options but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Your description is too less. You need to provide a detailed information like what exactly you had tried and what output you got. It can be possible that you did not create registry entry properly. Please try to provide detailed information with snapshot may help us to understand the issue in better way.

Comment: I created registry entry as mentioned above but what we are suppose to do after that. I tried to fix with enterprise mode and compatibility view but that didn't work

Comment: As per your requirement in the original post, This registry entry will just set the IE document mode to IE 10. In your last comment, You are talking about fixing enterprise mode and compatibility view. To get the helpful suggestion ,you need to provide the details about your overall issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: The solution works great. If someone needs a different version other than 10 they can find the corresponding numbers here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)